# Serviço me retorna erro de cast ao ser consumido

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, expressões-lambda

Resolvi fazer outro post, já que o assunto é outro, apesar que no post original, nos comentários chegamos a tocar no assunto, mas sem profundidade.
Tenho esse erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The specified cast from a
>   materialized 'System.Double' type to the 'System.Single' type is not
>   valid.'

Não entendi o erro, já que no banco tenho os mesmos tipos que na aplicação. A diferença é que eu joguei na aplicação os campos float e decimal, fiz aceitar `null`, pois assim está no banco. Abaixo a minha classe Entity Model:

```
[Table("LIBERACAO")]
    public class Liberacao
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Column("ID_LIBERACAO")]
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_LIBERACAO")]
        public byte FlagLiberacao { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_ORCAMENTO")]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR")]
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR")]
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_FILIAL")]
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        [Column("FILIAL")]
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        [Column("DATALIB")]
        public float? DataLib { get; set; }
        [Column("HORALIB")]
        public float? HoraLib { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_CLIENTE")]
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        [Column("CLIENTE")]
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        [Column("TIPO_VENDA")]
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [Column("JUROS")]
        public float? Juros { get; set; }
        [Column("DESCONTO")]
        public float? Desconto { get; set; }
        [Column("VENCIMENTO")]
        public float? Vencimento { get; set; }
        [Column("ACRESCIMO")]
        public float? Acrescimo { get; set; }
        [Column("ENTRADA")]
        public float? Entrada { get; set; }
        [Column("PRAZO")]
        public float? Prazo { get; set; }
        [Column("TOTAL_LIQUIDO")]
        public float? TotalLiquido { get; set; }
        [Column("MIN_TOTAL")]
        public float? MinTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("USUARIO")]
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        [Column("CUSTODIARIO")]
        public decimal? CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [Column("MAX_COMI")]
        public decimal? MaxComi { get; set; }
        [Column("VALOR_COMI")]
        public decimal? ValorComi { get; set; }
        [Column("NOVA_COMI")]
        public decimal? NovaComi { get; set; }
        [Column("MENSSAGEM")]
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
        [Column("Menssagem_RET")]
        public string MensagemRet { get; set; }
        [Column("DataRetorno")]
        public double? DataRetorno { get; set; }
        [Column("HoraRetorno")]
        public double? HoraRetorno { get; set; }
        [Column("TempoProcesso")]
        public double? TempoPrecesso { get; set; }
        [Column("Tipo")]
        public int Tipo { get; set; }
        [Column("PROGRAMA")]
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PC")]
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        [Column("NOME_PROCEDURE")]
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        [Column("Perc_Juros_Total")]
        public decimal? PercJurosTotal { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_CULTURAVENCIDA")]
        public byte FlagCulturaVencida { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA")]
        public string Cultura { get; set; }
        [Column("CULTURA_VCTO")]
        public int CulturaVcto { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_PRORROGADO")]
        public byte FlagProrrogado { get; set; }
        [Column("VALOR_PRORROGADO")]
        public double? ValorProrrogado { get; set; }
        [Column("DIAS_ATRASO")]
        public int DiasAtrazo { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_VENDEDOR2")]
        public int IdVendedor2 { get; set; }
        [Column("VENDEDOR2")]
        public string Vendedor2 { get; set; }
        [Column("COMISSAO_VEND2")]
        public double? ComissaoVend2 { get; set; }
        [Column("FLAG_COTACAO")]
        public byte FlagCotacao { get; set; }
        [Column("TipoVenda")]
        public string TipoVenda1 { get; set; }
        [Column("Flag_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public byte FlagReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
        [Column("Autorizou_Receber_Atrasado")]
        public string AutorizouReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
    }
```

Seguindo as orientações do colega Gabriel(outro post), criei uma classe LiberacaoDTO, mas apenas criei a classe com esse nome. Não sei se devo fazer uma outra coisa, para entender que não é só um nome, mas uma DTO de verdade. Não estou seguro se fiz certo ou não. Abaixo a classe:

```
public class LiberacaoDTO
    {
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        public byte FlagLiberacao { get; set; }
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        public float? DataLib { get; set; }
        public float? HoraLib { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        public float? Juros { get; set; }
        public float? Desconto { get; set; }
        public float? Vencimento { get; set; } 
        public float? Acrescimo { get; set; }
        public float? Entrada { get; set; }
        public float? Prazo { get; set; }
        public float? TotalLiquido { get; set; }
        public float? MinTotal { get; set; }
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        public decimal? CustoDiario { get; set; }
        public decimal? MaxComi { get; set; }
        public decimal? ValorComi { get; set; }
        public decimal? NovaComi { get; set; }
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
        public string MensagemRet { get; set; }
        public double? DataRetorno { get; set; }
        public double? HoraRetorno { get; set; }
        public double? TempoPrecesso { get; set; }
        public int Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        public decimal? PercJurosTotal { get; set; }
        public byte FlagCulturaVencida { get; set; }
        public string Cultura { get; set; }
        public int CulturaVcto { get; set; }
        public byte FlagProrrogado { get; set; }
        public double? ValorProrrogado { get; set; }
        public int DiasAtrazo { get; set; }
        public int IdVendedor2 { get; set; }
        public string Vendedor2 { get; set; }
        public double? ComissaoVend2 { get; set; }
        public byte FlagCotacao { get; set; }
        public string TipoVenda1 { get; set; }
        public byte FlagReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
        public string AutorizouReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
    }
```

O método que popula a DTO e retorna uma lista para o serviço:

```
public class PedidoLiberacao
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        Liberacao liberacao = new Liberacao();

        public List<LiberacaoDTO> getAutoriza(int idorcamento)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        .Where(lib => lib.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
                        .Select(lib => new LiberacaoDTO
                        {
                            TipoVenda = lib.TipoVenda,
                            Vencimento = lib.Vencimento,
                            Juros = lib.Juros,
                            Entrada = lib.Entrada,
                            Acrescimo = lib.Acrescimo,
                            Desconto = lib.Desconto,
                            Mensagem = lib.Mensagem,
                            DataLib = lib.DataLib,
                            Vendedor = lib.Vendedor,
                            Cliente = lib.Cliente,
                            Filial = lib.Filial
                        }).ToList();

            return lista;
        }
    }
```

Aqui o meu serviço que pega o retorno do método acima:

```
public class LiberacaoController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        PedidoLiberacao liberacao = new PedidoLiberacao();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<LiberacaoDTO> getLiberacao()
        {
            return liberacao.getAutoriza(1000012093).AsEnumerable().ToList();
            //return contexto.Liberacoes.AsEnumerable().ToList();
         }
    }
```

Abaixo o meu sql server e o banco e os campos listados(alguns por questão de espaço)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pergunta é: se eu estou no caminho, por que o erro acima?

Esse é o stack trace do erro

> em
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader
>   reader, Int32 ordinal)    em lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )    em
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper)    em
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    em
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   em System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    em
>   AutorizadorService.Controllers.LiberacaoController.getLiberacao() na
>   C:\Projetos\AutorizadorService\AutorizadorService\Controllers\LiberacaoController.cs:linha
>   22    em lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    em
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    em
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    em
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

Comment: Este tipo de erro ocorre ao comparar tipos incompatíveis dentro de uma expressão lambda. Por um acaso **IdOrcamento** é de fato um **int**? Não seria um **long**?

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck, realment não sei. No banco ele foi declarado como int, mas os valores dele são grande, tipo: `1000012093`. Isso tá mais pra long que int, correto? Pode ser isso, um dos exemplos. Ou seja, indo por essa lógica, o fato de no bd estar como int, não necessariamente é um int no C#, podendo ser um long e etc...

Comment: Então seu problema está no mapeamento. Mude o int para long e seja feliz

Comment: Ainda não fui feliz, o erro continua. Sei lá, tá estranho. Fiz um serviço semelhante, mas em outro banco(banco que eu criei) e funciona fino, com método retornando da mesma forma. Nesse tem um campo, DataLib, que é um float no banco(ele armazena uma data) e tenho outros assim(hora) e ainda desconfio desse campo. Esse banco eu não criei, apenas rodei o script dessas três tabelas para eu poder fazer os testes em ambiente "real".

Comment: O DTO, criação da query estão corretas, seu erro continua sendo nos valores atribuidos. Perceba que o erro não é mais o mesmo da antiga pergunta. Valide todos os tipos das suas propriedades para garantir que não acontece igual o amigo comentou, de um int receber um número muito grande.

Comment: Não sei mais o que fazer, estou tentando e seguindo as orientações de vocês e mesmo assim não está dando certo. Continua o erro de cast.

Comment: Esse pode ser um dos problemas. Isso é um problema de Culture da sua aplicação, certas cultura aceita o ponto como casa decimal, enquanto outras aceita a virgula.

Comment: @GabrielColetta e tem mais isso. Existe campos na tabela do tipo real e como eu os represento no C#? Eu coloquei como double, mas pode ser que isso esteja barrando a aploicação. Esses tipos REAL no banco, são para campos hora e data. Será isso?

Comment: O real do SQL Server é somente um float com tamanho maior, tudo que o float não aceita ele também não vai aceitar.

Comment: Me disseram que esse erro pode ser bug do Entity e há uma ferramenta que corrige isso, um tal Repair Tool. Procede isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64432/discussion-between-gabriel-coletta-and-pnet).

Comment: Percebi que por mais que eu declare em minha model o tipo float ou double ou até Double, o Entity está entendendo que eu tenho um tipo Single e ao pegar no banco o tipo float, ele diz que não é possível a conversão. O que passa que não sei o que fazer, já que é uma interpretação do Entity, assim penso eu.

Comment: Tanto na DTO quanto no mapping da entidade você deve usar double ao invés de float.

Comment: Apesar do valor 1000012093 ser grande, ainda é um int, o int pode chegar até 2147483647